# Webpack ReferenceError: require is not defined (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I understand this error happens when the `require()` function is called in the browser as opposed to within node. However, I can't seem to understand what exactly I need to do to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can go to the following repo for whole code base https://github.com/thegreekjester/React_SSR.

Steps to run and reproduce the issue:

- npm install
- npm run dev
- open `localhost:3000` in browser
- You will see the error in the console

Webpack.client.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {

  // production || development
  mode: 'development',

  // Inform webpack that we're building a bundle
  // for nodeJS, rather then for the browser
  target: 'node',

  // Tell webpack the root file of our
  // server application
  entry: './src/client.js',

  // Tell webpack where to put the output file
  // that is generated
  output: {
    filename: 'client_bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/public'),
    publicPath: '/build/public'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react', 'stage-0', ['env', {
              target: 'web'
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Webpack.server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {

  // production || development
  mode: 'development',

  // Inform webpack that we're building a bundle
  // for nodeJS, rather then for the browser
  target: 'node',

  // Tell webpack the root file of our
  // server application
  entry: './server.js',

  // Tell webpack where to put the output file
  // that is generated
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react', 'stage-0', ['env', {
              target: { browsers: ['last 2 versions']}
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  // Tell webpack not to bundle any libraries that exist in the 'node_modules' folder
  // into the server bundle
  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()]

};
```

Comment: It is because of this package `@optimizely/optimizely-sdk`. I just removed this packages usage from the `configureStore.js` file, and everything is working fine. I am not familiar with this packages usage but seems like you are using it wrong.!!

Comment: Hello @RaghavGarg thank you for your quick response and help with the editing of the question. The file 'optimizelyReducer' is just a reducer file for redux that 
 has some dependencies. Even if you take out the initial import statement (from optimizelyReducer.js), the next one (axios) will still cause that error.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Please see my answer for the actual issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `webpack.client.js`, please remove the key `target: 'node'`, because webpack bundling for the client(browser).

In your `webpack.server.js`, please add a key `libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'` to `output`. It would look something like this:

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
},
```